# Generate HFileOutputFormat after the Reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I have written a MapReduce-Job, which needs the Mapper and the Reducer part. After the Reducer (which generates the Puts) I would like to save the result into HFileOutputFormat to do an incremental load.

Here is my problem because the HFileOutputFormat needs also a Reducer to generate the HFile. And as far as I know, it’s not possible to have two Reducers in sequence.

In the Reducer I wrote the generated Puts directly into the context and get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue
```

Then I tried to build a ChainReducer which passes the Puts to an additional Mapper. These Mapper only write the given Puts back to the context. So now it should be possible to execute the Reducer for the HFile. But then I got these exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put<init>()
```

What can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Toby